# Trying to look for "(" in sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed

This might be a dumb question but are `(` `)` supported by sed? I know `\\(` and `\\)` hold what is between them so you can access it by `\1` or whatever number. I need a regex to look for parentheses and save what is between them.

```
sed 's/.*( .* \([[:alnum:]]+\) *).*/\1/' file
```

So I am looking for this:

> possibly some stuff ( possibly some stuff [letters or numbers] possibly some stuff )

I need the outer `()`s to be found, but you can't `\` them or else it thinks you want to save what is inside.  Basically I only need to find the `()`s so I can save some stuff inside them.

I am going to keep looking for how to do this but if any of you know how it would really help me out.  I tried using `""` and `''` and unless I used incorrect syntax of some kind that doesn't work. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Edit:Specific example:  I want:

```
    aname = (type name){ value, value }.
```

I want to know how to look for ()s and {} specifically in sed because they have other meanings.  I assume \{ and \} is how you get {}s but I am not sure how to get ()s.  Also I know the previous sed expression won't find that, it was just a quick example I wrote down in order to show that I want to look for () in the regex.  I am sorry if I have caused any confusion. Just so you guys can see this is my current regex:

```
    start line   aname        =          (        type           name    )         { values }; 

    sed 's/^\([[:alnum:]]\)+ *={1} *[^()]({1} *[[:alnum:]]+ +\([[:alnum:]]\)+ *) *\{{1}\(.*\)\};/init_\2\( \&\1, \3)/' file
```

Comment: If you really copied and pasted your real code, then you have one obvious typo: `[[:alunum:]]`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean its always been [[:alnum:]] hehe.Thank you but yea the real thing looks for more than that I just wrote that down real quick to get my point across. But good eye sir.

Comment: Do you really have spaces between the regex-y things you want to match, or are you assuming `sed` ignores them? It doesn't.

Comment: I know it doesn't ignore spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed (and other utilities which use Posix Basic Regular Expressions) don't give any special meaning to `(` and `)` so you can just use them like any other character. `\(` and `\)` are the group delimiters.

BRE's really should die. Long, long ago, Posix defined "Extended" Regular Expressions (EREs) in which the grouping delimiters are `(` and `)` and you use `\(` and `\)` to match parentheses, which is a lot more intuitive. There is a similar difference between BRE and ERE treatment of `{` and `}` (numerical repetition operators). EREs also include the `|` and `+` operators.

`grep` and `sed` both default to using BREs, but can be persuaded to use EREs with the correct command-line flag: `grep -E` and `sed -r`. gawk uses EREs with some GNU extensions and some deviations from the standard, including the fact that you must specify --re-interval if you want to use `{` and `}`. [rant]It sometimes amazes me that we tolerate all this insanity. There should be just one regex standard, and all utilities should use it without exceptions.[/rant]

If your regex with `(` and `)` is not working as you expect, please provide specific examples of patterns which it fails on, and your expected outcome. My suspicion is that it has to do with the space characters in your pattern, if that is actually the pattern you're using.

Comment: Note that `sed -r` is a GNU `sed` extension compared to POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).  In POSIX 2008, there isn't an `egrep` or `fgrep` and [`grep -E` and `grep -F`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) are the standard equivalents, though it is likely to be a while (decade or two) before the original programs completely die.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is quite right; it's been so long since I've used FreeBSD that I'd forgotten that FreeBSD's sed uses -E, just like grep. I didn't mention grep -F, which has the effect of making the pattern just a literal pattern, an option which doesn't exist in sed, as far as I know. I stand by my rant, for which this is just another perfect illustration.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is a greedy match that first .* pattern takes.

try to replace it with [^()]* to exclude parenthes:

```
bash$ echo 'xxx(123)yyy' | sed -e 's/[^()]*(\([[:alnum:]]*\))[^()]*/\1/' ->
123
```